# Apply SSL into Google Compute Engine Instance

Tags: ssl, https, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I am new to **Google Cloud Platform**.

I bought a wildcard SSL and would like to know how to install Wildcard SSL into a **Google Cloud Compute** instance?

I used Cloud Shell to generate a **CSR** on **Google Cloud Platform** by using the following line of command, 
**`openssl req -new -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -keyout yourdomain.key -out yourdomain.csr`**

I managed to activate my certification and received the **`ca-bundle`** files.

But I don't know what's the next step to install the SSL. I can't find anything about SSL in the **Google Compute Engine** tab.

[How to install a SSL certificate on Google Cloud Platform](https://helpdesk.ssls.com/hc/en-us/articles/115001608812-How-to-generate-a-CSR-on-GoogleCloud-platform)

As the website above show, I must activate my SSL via **App Engine**  but I have doubt on it.

Answer (score 14):

There are different scenarios where SSL certificates can be used in GCP.  The steps of the document  you have linked applies for GAE but not for GCE.

If you have GCE instances running behind a load balancer, the certificate must be uploaded there. You can find the details on this [article](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/http/ssl-certificates#createresource).

If you are not using a GCE LB and instead your instances are serving traffic directly, you must configure the certificate on the server.  I.e. for NGINX you can follow [these](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/configuring_https_servers.html) instructions.

Comment: If you have GCE VM's behind a GCE LB, you should ('must' under most compliance scenarios) have SSL/TLS terminated on the VM as well as on the LB because the LB-to-VM traffic is publicly routed (LB's are outside firewalls). I can't find specific tooling to help with that, particularly for using SA-signed (non-spoofable) certs for autoscaled vm's behind a LB.